# Is Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 compatible with GPL v2+?

Tags: licensing

I have found some code that is licensed under *[Creative Commons Attribution 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/legalcode)* (CC-BY 3.0).

I want to pick it and put it into a program that I downloaded that is licensed under GPL v2+.

Then I want to publicly distribute the remixed work in one software-package under GPL v2+ (GPL v2 or at the users wish a later version) again.

I'm Wondering if it is possible or not. I was already looking for license-compatiblity on the GNU website, but it has [only some information about the CC-BY 2.0 License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#ccby):

> #### Creative Commons Attribution 2.0 license (a.k.a. CC-BY)
>
> This is a non-copyleft free license that is good for art and entertainment works, and educational works. Please don't use it for software or documentation, since it is incompatible with the GNU GPL and with the GNU FDL.

In that statement it's written that CC-BY 2.0 is incompatible with GPL-

So is the *Creative Commons Attribution 3.0* license incompatible with the *[GNU GPL v2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html) or later* as well?

---

#### More Details

**Update:** It has been asked to add some more specific details to this question, here they are:

1. The example bit of code that is under CC-BY 3.0 is here: [example-so-5462305.php](https://gist.github.com/5c233e5dbf42618ebe9e).
2. The code I'd like to integrate this into is here: [Joomla_1.6.1-Stable-Full_Package.zip](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/14236/62394/Joomla_1.6.1-Stable-Full_Package.zip)

My questions about license compatibility is about to incorporate [1.] into [2.] (become part of existing code in form of a PHP class member), create a patch, add it to the publicly known repository of the project that is driving [2.] and expect it to get released then with a future version of [2.].

Comment: This question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to answer unless you give some details about the bits of code you consider and how they will be combined and depend on each other.
Can you provide specifics about each piece of code? Urls, etc?

For instance the [famfamafam silk icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) (not really software per se) are under a CC-BY license (CC BY 2.5). They are often combined with GPL-licensed code and nobody seems to care too much.

Some other pointers to relevant discussions:
[Using a CC-3.0-BY file as data file for a GPL program](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-legal@lists.debian.org/msg37375.html)

https://superuser.com/questions/113591/is-it-ok-to-use-images-of-gpld-code-in-a-cc-3-0-by-video

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, the links did not cover the type of licensing I'd like to do (but the one to the mailing-list was especially interesting). I'm actually concerned about putting code into code and made this more clear in my question now.

Comment: I checked out the code, and this is a question for Joomla folks to answer if that would be OK by them. I had some involvement there a few years back. Nice chaps. The simplest alternative might be to contact the CC-BY code author and ask for a GPL license

Comment: How can Joomla allow usage under GPL if CC-BY 3.0 would not offer the needed rights to do so?

Comment: @hakre license and what it considered acceptable is really a matter of interpretation: hence why you should ask Joomla folks

Comment: @Philippe - let's shift the parameters slightly and say I (not the joomla project) want to release the changed package under GPL then. How about that?

Comment: @ hakre the CC-BY 3.0 license says: "You may not sublicense the Work."

Comment: That means, release in a GPL'ed package is not possible, it requires all code *at least* under GPL. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @hakre technically yes. Practically, there are cases when including both could be considered as side-by-side redistribution, and ok per the GPL: it all depends how the code bits under diferent licenses "interact" together. IMHO the GPL intention is in general not to prohibit combined usage of free and open source components together, though as pointed the devil is in the details in some cases. /HTH IANAL, TINLA

Comment: @hakre and for reference, the GPL does not require "all code at least under the GPL" ... in V3, the key is "A “covered work” means either the unmodified Program or a work based on the Program." and what a "work based on the Program" is a really a legal determination...  and when everything is conveyed as source in modifiable forms then you may comply with the GPL in some case of combination of non-GPL with GPL-licensed code. YMMV -IANAL, TINLA

Comment: No, because all source has to be (at least) under GPL. You can not bring it together in a for distribution/conveysion form any other way. Copyleft that's pretty clear. And for the legal codification of "work based on the Program", contact your lawyer first. AFAIK this has much more meaning than just being (the often mythical so undeterminable told derivative work form as V2 is often "word attacked" [legal attacks have only proven this wrong so far]). You didn't think that this kind of feedback wouldn't gone into V3 from the legal side? I'd say, you should better take it not that "clever".

Comment: @hakre where do you get that "all source has to be (at least) under GPL" in the GPL?

Comment: I don't understand your question, GPL is a copyleft license so that's how it works.